# SSH access even if your CMD is closed

Tags: server, ssh, localhost

Please I want some help
My work manager gives me SSH access to a local server using the command : `shh user@local_ip` to work on a data sciences project
The running time is so long and if I close my CMD, the running process will be stopped
And while the code running, if I tried to open another CMD or Powershell window to connect to the server, then using the command : `screen -list`, the output is 0 sockets
I want a way to keep my code running on the server even if I close the CMD window
Note: There's no public hosting, No RDP access

Is there a way to do that?

Thank's for listening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your script with `screen` in the first place, this is not done automatically. Otherwise there won't be anything in `screen -list`.

1. Run `screen`
2. Start your script
3. Press Ctrl - A, then D to detach from your screen.
4. You can exit the session

To reattach, run `screen -r` or if there are multiple screens running `screen -r <ID>`. Check the IDs with `screen -ls`.
You can also give a session name with `screen -S <NAME>`, then you can run `screen -r <NAME>`.